# DotNetOpenAuth : "No OpenID endpoint found" on IIS but runs fine on VS development server

Tags: iis-7.5, dotnetopenauth

I am running the OpenIDRelyingPartyWebForms sample from the DotNetOpenAuth release.

I have VS 10, IIS 7.5, Windows 7.

When I run the project using the development server, it works fine and I navigate to the OpenId login page. It works with both F5 and Ctrl F5,

When I add the project as an application inside IIS 7.5, I get the "No OpenID endpoint found" error.

Any ideas?

Where are the VS development server settings stored so I can compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Is the IIS 7.5 server the same as your dev box or is it a different box?  Usually firewalls are to blame for this.

Perhaps the best way to diagnose it is to [enable verbose logging](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) and see if DNOA tells you more about why it is failing.

Comment: Yes - both IIS are on the same box so doesn't look like a firewall issue?

Comment: well, then, that leaves logging.